# ERROR: "The project doesn't know how to run the profile IIS Express" (VS 2019, 16.10.1)

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, iis, web-applications, iis-express

I'm super new to coding altogether, and I'm googling as much as I can, but nothing is addressing my latest problem:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/quickstart-aspnet-core?view=vs-2019

I followed this, just trying to get my feet wet, but when I get to the part where I run the webpage in IIS Express, I get an error that says, "The project doesn't know how to run the profile IIS Express."

I did see this, it seems to come closest to addressing the problem, but I'm not sure how to apply the fix, or even quite what it all means:

https://elanderson.net/2017/06/visual-studio-2017-error-the-project-doesnt-know-how-to-run-the-profile-iis-express/?fbclid=IwAR1ISIOAA6rap5Kll6tYc5H43ZzKFvNbRfRyaTtOPt5BZDBUO6xrZ55Ph70

If this is what I need, how do I do it? If it's not... what do I need to get my debug running in a web browser?

Thanks a ton!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular how to [ask]. Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use visual studio installer, repair the installation and restart your program.
[image]

Comment: I suspect this will work for a lot of people who have the same underlying problem that I did. In my case, I think I tried to be too clever setting up VS as bare bones as I could, by not just accepting the Web Dev workload and picking what I needed myself. In doing so, some link was obviously missing between VS and IISExpress that was fixed by the upgrade, but would probably be fixed by a Repair too.